# For..In loops in JavaScript - key value pairs

Tags: javascript, foreach

I was wondering if there's a way to do something like a PHP `foreach` loop in JavaScript. The functionality I'm looking for is something like this PHP Snippet:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) { }
```

I was looking at the JS `for..in` loop, but there seems to be no way to specify the `as`. If I do this with a 'normal' for loop (`for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++`), is there a way to grab the key => value pairs?

Answer (score 445, accepted):

If you can use [ES6](http://es6-features.org/) natively or with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) (js compiler) then you could do the following:

```js
const test = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(test)) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Which will print out this output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property `[key, value]` pairs, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop ***(the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well)***.

- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) documentation
- [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) documentation
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) documentation
- [Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) documentation

Comment: This works perfect, just wondering - compared to "for key in object and then get value by object[key]", which one gives better performance?

Comment: In this specific case I would assume it's slower because of the `Object.entries` call. I didn't run any tests though.

Comment: this is the best answer to the question at hand, which asked about grabbing both key and value in the for loop.

Comment: The accepted answer should be updated since this actually answers the question, although it wasn't available at time of the question.

Comment: You might want to check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213651/caught-between-two-no-restricted-syntax-violations
which seems to indicate that a syntax of this type would be recommended:
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(key => {...

Comment: carefull when using this with file object

Comment: Is there an IE-friendly version?

Comment: Just answered my own question...It doesn't work in IE. Use the answer directly below for a solution to this.

Answer (score 565):

```
for (var k in target){
    if (target.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
         alert("Key is " + k + ", value is " + target[k]);
    }
}
```

`hasOwnProperty` is used to check if your `target` really has that property, rather than having inherited it from its prototype. A bit simpler would be:

```
for (var k in target){
    if (typeof target[k] !== 'function') {
         alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + target[k]);
    }
}
```

It just checks that `k` is not a method (as if `target` is `array` you'll get a lot of methods alerted, e.g. `indexOf`, `push`, `pop`,etc.)

Comment: Another way to iterate only over "own" properties is `Object.keys`. `Object.keys(target).forEach(function (key) { target[key]; });`.

Comment: not going to work if `target` is created using `Object.create(null)`, code should be changed `target.hasOwnProperty(k)` -> `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(target,k)`

Comment: why not to use variables given in question example? What here is `k`, `target` and `property`? For me, non-javascripter this area of undefined :)

Comment: Object.keys(target).forEach((key) => { target[key]; }); for Angular

Comment: I would say that almost every time you see `obj.hasOwnProperty(k)` it should be rewritten as `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)`. If you don't know whether or not an object has an own property `k`, then you probably also don't know *for sure* whether it has an own property named `"hasOwnProperty"`; and if it does, you don't want that one, you want the one from `Object.prototype`. So IMO making `hasOwnProperty` a method at all was a design flaw in the language; nobody ever wants its behaviour to be overridden in practice.

Answer (score 345):

No one has mentioned `Object.keys` so I'll mention it.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
   // do something with obj[key]
});
```

Comment: Note: Not supported by IE8 and below.

Comment: At this point you should be using an ES5 shim. If you're living in the nice ES6 future use `for of` http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/for-of/

Comment: It is worth noting, that "There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception"

Comment: Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => { }); for Angular

Comment: It doesn't work on ES6 or I don't understand it. Felix has a better and more readable answer below:
data.forEach(function(value, index) { console.log(index); // 0 , 1, 2... });

Comment: I like this approach because it enables function chaining

Comment: this isn't ideal for function chaining because it does not return a result, but instead produces a side effect--usually function chaining is used in a functional way. If you want to act on an array in a functional chaining style, better to use 'map' or 'reduce', etc.

Comment: to those worried about not being able to exit the loop--while that is true, if you need to stop it mid-run, you should probably be used a different method, like Array's  'some()' or 'every()' or 'find()'.

Answer (score 145):

[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) will work for you.

```
for( var key in obj ) {
  var value = obj[key];
}
```

In modern JavaScript you can also do this:

```
for ( const [key,value] of Object.entries( obj ) ) {

}
```

Answer (score 72):

```
var obj = {...};
for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];

}
```

The php syntax is just sugar.

Comment: This will also iterate on all inherited properties. To avoid this, use .hasOwnProperty().

Answer (score 28):

I assume you know that `i` is the key and that you can get the value via `data[i]` (and just want a shortcut for this).

ECMAScript5 introduced [`forEach` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach) for arrays (it seems you have an array):

```
data.forEach(function(value, index) {

});
```

The MDN documentation provides a shim for browsers not supporting it.

Of course this does not work for objects, but you can create a similar function for them:

```
function forEach(object, callback) {
    for(var prop in object) {
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            callback(prop, object[prop]);
        }
    }
}
```

Since you tagged the question with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), jQuery provides [`$.each` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) which loops over both, array and object structures.

Comment: That's Array `forEach`, not object `forEach`.

Comment: So? Apparently the OP is looping over an array.

Comment: Also Mozilla (Firefox, SpiderMonkey-C, Rhino &c) has an non-standard extension that allows `for each` syntax. `for each (let val in myObj) console.log(val);`.

Comment: @katspaugh: Right, but as it is Mozilla only, it does not seem to be very useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll read over the information you provided. Your assumption at the start of the answer was right, I knew that, except I got so much on my head with this project that I can't focus and forgot about it.. Thank you.

Comment: Ugh. `Object.keys(obj).forEach`. Everyone knows you should iterate over the keys.

Comment: @Raynos: Not every ES5 feature completely got to me ;) It still would not give you the corresponding value.

Answer (score 12):

There are three options to deal with keys and values of an object:

1. Select values:

   ```js
   Object.values(obj).forEach(value => ...);
   ```
2. Select keys:

   ```js
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => ...);
   ```
3. Select keys and values:

   ```js
   Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => ...);
   ```

Answer (score 10):

```
for (var key in myMap) {
    if (myMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log("key =" + key);
        console.log("value =" + myMap[key]);
    }
}
```

In javascript, every object has a bunch of built-in key-value pairs that have meta-information. When you loop through all the key-value pairs for an object you're looping through them too. The use of hasOwnProperty() filters these out.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `for..in` for that.

```
for (var key in data)
{
    var value = data[key];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
let test = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
Object.entries(test).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value))

// a 1
// b 2
// c 3
```

Comment: You may add some explanation with the code you posted instead of posting a plain code which might be not understandable.

Comment: Object.entries pulls out an array of arrays based on the key/value pairs of the original object: `[['a', 1],['b',2],['c',3]]`.  The `forEach` deconstructs each of the key/value arrays and sets the two variables to `key` and `value`, to be used as you want the in function - here output in `console.log`.

Answer (score 5):

In the last few year since this question was made, Javascript has added a few new features.   One of them is the [Object.Entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method.

Copied directly from MDN is the follow code snippet

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ES6 will provide Map.prototype.forEach(callback) which can be used like this

```
myMap.forEach(function(value, key, myMap) {
                        // Do something
                    });
```

Comment: what's the parameter `myMap` for?

Comment: A map is not an object. They are completely separate things.

Comment: The forEach function does not contain the 'key' of the array but more the index of the element that you are currently iterating.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 'for in' loop for this:

```
for (var key in bar) {
     var value = bar[key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example that gets as close as you get.

```
for(var key in data){
  var value = data[key];    
  //your processing here
}
```

If you're using jQuery see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach), you can use `_.forEach`

```
_.forEach({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }, function(value, key) {
  console.log(key + ": " + value);
});
// => Logs 'a: 1' then 'b: 2' (iteration order is not guaranteed).
```

Answer (score 0):

why not simply this

```
var donuts = [
{ type: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
{ type: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
{ type: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
{ type: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }];

donuts.forEach(v => {console.log(v["type"]+ " donuts cost $"+v["cost"]+" each")});
```

Comment: Why not include an educational explanation?  The OP is wanting to grab the key and value from a 1-dimensional structure -- your answer is ignoring this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

```
<script> 
 const games = {
  "Fifa": "232",
  "Minecraft": "476",
  "Call of Duty": "182"
 };

Object.keys(games).forEach((item, index, array) => {
  var msg = item+' '+games[item];
  console.log(msg);
});
```

Comment: Why is `array` there if you aren't using it?  How is your answer valuable versus the same advice from 5 years earlier?

Answer (score -2):

yes, you can have associative arrays also in javascript:

```
var obj = 
{
    name:'some name',
    otherProperty:'prop value',
    date: new Date()
};
for(i in obj)
{
    var propVal = obj[i]; // i is the key, and obj[i] is the value ...
}
```

Comment: @PaulPRO ... everything in javascript is a key-value pair (thus, an object is in fact an associative array of key-value pairs...)

Comment: @AlexPacurar and assocative array has an order. An object is unordered. _thats_ a big difference

Comment: @Raynos you may be right... it will be a great help to explain exactly how an object is unordered... given the above example, one would expect that the 'i' in the for loop to be [name, otherProperty, and finally date]... so in which situation the order of properties of an object will be mixed ?

Comment: @AlexPacurar the particular order in which it will loop over the object is browser specific. Some do it alphabetically, some do it order of definition, etc

Comment: @Raynos: Are associative arrays necessarily ordered? I've often seen the term used more generally. For example, on [the Associative array Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

Answer (score -9):

```
var global = (function() {
   return this;
})();

// Pair object, similar to Python

function Pair(key, value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;

    this.toString = function() {
       return "(" + key + ", " + value + ")";
    };
}

/**
 * as function
 * @param {String} dataName A String holding the name of your pairs list.
 * @return {Array:Pair} The data list filled
 *    with all pair objects.
 */
Object.prototype.as = function(dataName) {
    var value, key, data;
    global[dataName] = data = [];

    for (key in this) {
       if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          value = this[key];

          (function() {
             var k = key,
                 v = value;

            data.push(new Pair(k, v));
          })();
       }
    }

    return data;
};

var d = {
   'one': 1,
   'two': 2
};

// Loop on your (key, list) pairs in this way
for (var i = 0, max = d.as("data").length; i < max; i += 1) {
   key = data[i].key;
   value = data[i].value;

   console.log("key: " + key + ", value: " + value);
}

// delete data when u've finished with it.
delete data;
```