# How to modify each JSON object javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to modify each JSON value inside the `cooldown` object

```
{
  "cooldown":{
    "user": 1, // This
    "user2": 0 // This
  }
}
```

using a for statement in Javascript.

I've researched for hours and only could find a for inside `[]` blocks.

**Edit**

This is what I've tried:

```
for (var i in db["cooldown"]) {
  i = time.ms;
}
```

Comment: please add some examples to illustrate you problem.

Comment: This is not clear. What is your current JSON and what is the expected outcome you want.

Comment: I believe what you are actually asking is how to loop over each key/value pair in an object. If this is the case, perhaps this post will be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241878/for-in-loops-in-javascript-key-value-pairs

Comment: Your solution is close - but the `i` variable you are getting is not the value - it is the key. So you'd need to do something like `db["cooldown"][i]`

Comment: Ah okay, thank you again! :)

Comment: Those are not "JSONs". They are just plain old "fields", "properties", "key-value pairs", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to return array of keys and then use  `forEach()` to loop that array and return each value.

```js
var data = {
  "cooldown": {
    "user": 1, // This
    "user2": 0 // This
  }
}

Object.keys(data.cooldown).forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(data.cooldown[e]);
})
```

You can also use `for...in` loop

```js
var data = {
  "cooldown": {
    "user": 1, // This
    "user2": 0 // This
  }
}

for (var k in data.cooldown) {
  console.log(data.cooldown[k]);
}
```

Comment: Does this require JQuery?

Comment: So I'm trying to create an if statement to check if a value is equal to zero, and it's completely ignoring that. Would you like me to post my code in an edit or ask a new question?

Comment: I added a comment inside the fiddle to explain what I want to do.

Comment: Its never zero its -1 and 5.

Comment: So change the if statement to be == -1?

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want but if you want to return each user when value is -1 you can do this https://jsfiddle.net/y322s88e/1/

Comment: Hold on, I'm going to post a new question.

Comment: If you want to end loop at first -1 and return that user then better option is to use find like this https://jsfiddle.net/y322s88e/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `for..in` method to loop through the object

```
var jsonObj = {
    "cooldown":{
    "user": 1,
    "user2": 0
  }
};


for(var key in jsonObj["cooldown"]){
    jsonObj["cooldown"][key] = "modified value";
}

console.log(jsonObj);
```