# Caught between two no-restricted-syntax violations

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

This is my original code:

```
const buildTableContent = (settings) => {
  const entries = [];
  for (const key in settings) {
    for (const subkey in env[key]) {
```

`settings` is basically a dictionary of dictionary

```
  {  
    'env': {'name': 'prod'}, 
    'sass: {'app-id': 'a123445', 'app-key': 'xxyyzz'}
  }
```

It triggered the following AirBnb style guide error:

> 35:3  error  for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain,
>   which is virtually never what you want. Use
>   Object.{keys,values,entries}, and  iterate over the resulting array 
>   no-restricted-syntax

So I change the code to

```
const buildTableContent = (settings) => {
  const entries = [];
  for (const key of Object.keys(settings)) {
    for (const subkey of Object.keys(env[key])) {
```

as suggested.

Now when I run `lint`, I got this:

> 35:3  error  iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime,  which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately,
>   loops  should be avoided in favor of array iterations 
>   no-restricted-syntax

So it looks to me either way they are violating some lint style.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You'd want to use

```
Object.keys(settings).forEach(key => {
  Object.keys(env[key]).forEach(subkey => {
```

or potentially `Object.entries` or `Object.values` depending on if you actually want the keys.

Comment: I am using redux-saga where I have to sequentially call api using the yield keyword..yield cannot be used in the function callback for forEach since the callback is not a generator function.So I am stuck with the two errors mentioned in the question. Is there a way out ?

Comment: @anuragb26 Which rule? I'd probably just turn it off.

Comment: 'no-restricted-syntax': ...Yeah , i turned it off

Comment: @anuragb26 in order to use yield you may do something like this
for (const elem of elemArray){ 
  yield fn()
}

Comment: why using forEach is preferred?

Comment: @HojatModaresi I don't think it is preferred, but this question was explicitly about what to do when ESLint rules are in place to disallow it. If you want to use `for...of` then don't use the lint rules the OP is using.

Comment: To be explicit: Use **/* eslint-disable no-restricted-syntax */** to turn it off in the entire file. And to turn off in the **rules** section of the config file use:  **'no-restricted-syntax': ['off', 'ForOfStatement']**,

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the official example from the node team on how to use [opendir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesopendirpath-options):

```
import { opendir } from 'node:fs/promises';

try {
  const dir = await opendir('./');
  for await (const dirent of dir)
    console.log(dirent.name);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

As you can see, they recommend using the **for-of** syntax along with **console.error**. Assuming that we can take their recommendation as worthy of consideration, then we might want to turn these rules off.

To turn them off for an entire file:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-syntax */
```

To turn them` off in the eslint configuration file that affects all of your source code:

```
rules: {
   'no-console': ['off'],
   'no-restricted-syntax': ['off', 'ForOfStatement'],
},
```

There are several variations we can use to write these rules, but this should be enough to get started.

Comment: That is an example, not a recommendation. But yeah, restricting `for … of` statements makes absolutely no sense in nodejs in 2023.

Comment: @Bergi, you make a good point, so I changed my wording from "definitive" to " worthy of consideration."

Comment: Well it still is not a recommendation. Nobody recommends using `console.log` in production code.