# array of objects: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined inside onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have searched for a way to remove single object from an array of objects if id variable equals the id of an object.

I use the array to know which checkboxes are selected so that related information will be collected for further processing.

example: https://jsbin.com/vicerewevi/edit?html,js,output

Error that I get when I select the checkboxes fast:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at vicerewevi.js:33
    at Function.each (jquery-3.1.0.js:368)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (vicerewevi.js:32)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.0.js:5110)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.0.js:4918)
```

above error occurs on the line if value.id == id:

```
// if checkbox is checked, add object to array and if unchecked remove object by 'id' from array
$('.checkbox').change( function(){

    var id = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'))
    var foo = $(this).parent().siblings().find('#foo').val()
    var bar = $(this).parent().siblings().find('#bar').val()

    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        var obj = {'id': id, 'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}
        jsonobjects.push(obj)
    } else {
        $.each(jsonobjects, function( index, value ) {
            if (value.id == id ) {
                jsonobjects.delete(index)
            }
        });
    }
    countChecked() // update count of checkboxes
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonobjects))
  $('#output').html(JSON.stringify(jsonobjects, null, ""))
});
```

I found this code below on SO (never worked with custom prototypes before) that I tried:

```
Array.prototype.delete = function(pos){
    this[pos] = undefined;
    var len = this.length - 1;
    for(var a = pos;a < this.length - 1;a++){
      this[a] = this[a+1];
    }
    this.pop();
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `value.getAttribute("id") == id` in place of `value.id == id` ? In case it's an element ?

Comment: By the way, instead of that weird `delete` method, you could just do `jsonobjects.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: @JonasW. thanks, I also added hasownproperty in simple for loop instead of $.each to check if element in array is not a array function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you `delete` entries from your array, the next time you iterate over it, you will get a `value` that is `undefined` for that particular "gap" in your array. Obviously, that does not have an `id` property.

To solve this, do not use `delete`, but use `filter` to create a new, filtered array, which will not have such gaps.

Replace:

```
    $.each(jsonobjects, function( index, value ) {
        if (value.id == id ) {
            jsonobjects.delete(index)
        }
    });
```

...with:

```
    jsonobjects = jsonobjects.filter(function( value ) {
        return value.id !== id;
    });
```

Or, if you want to stick to jQuery methods, use `$.grep`:

```
    jsonobjects = $.grep(jsonobjects, function( value ) {
        return value.id !== id;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have searched for a way to remove single object from an array of objects if id variable equals the id of an object.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 4 },
  { id: 5 }
];

const removeById = (arr, id) => arr.filter(e => e.id !== id);

const no2 = removeById(arr, 2);
const no5 = removeById(arr, 5);

console.log(no2);
console.log(no5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the `Array.filter` method and reassign `jsonobjects` to the filtered array like so instead of the delete method you created

`jsonObjects = jsonObjects.filter((value, index) => {
   return value.id !== id;
})`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I tried solution on this awnser [For..In loops in JavaScript - key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241878/for-in-loops-in-javascript-key-value-pairs)

```
for (var k in jsonobjects){
    if (jsonobjects.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        if (jsonobjects[k].id == id) {
            jsonobjects.splice(k, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This could leave an entry in the array if `jsonobjects` has two consecutive objects that both have the `id` value you want to remove. In that case only the first of the two will be deleted, since `splice` moves all remaining elements one index position backward, and the `for` loop will not revisit the same index which now has the next item. See for instance [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217333/remove-items-from-array-with-splice-in-for-loop).