# How to find a key in a Map, where the key contains a certain value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So if I have an object where the keys of the object are different `href's` that map to an object... how can I be returned a the key where the `href` contains a certain string...

For example:

```
const hrefMap = new Map<string, any>({
'www.hello.com/12345': {value: 1, color: 'red'},
'www.hello.com/0000': {value: 2, color: 'blue'}
})
```

I want to be able to do something where I can input `12345` and be returned `www.hello.com/12345`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For..In loops in JavaScript - key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241878/for-in-loops-in-javascript-key-value-pairs)

And then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread the Map's `.key()` iterator to get an array of keys (hrefs), and then use `Array.find()` to find an item that includes the string.

```js
const fn = (hashMap, str) => [...hashMap.keys()].find(k => k.includes(str))

const hrefMap = new Map([["www.hello.com/12345",{"value":1,"color":"red"}],["www.hello.com/0000",{"value":2,"color":"blue"}]])

const result = fn(hrefMap, '12345')

console.log(result)
```

Since `Map.keys()` returns an iterator, you can use `for...of` to go over it lazily (no need to create an array of keys):

```js
const fn = (hashMap, str) => {
  for(const key of hashMap.keys()) {
    if(key.includes(str)) return key;
  }
}

const hrefMap = new Map([["www.hello.com/12345",{"value":1,"color":"red"}],["www.hello.com/0000",{"value":2,"color":"blue"}]])

const result = fn(hrefMap, '12345')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
const hrefMap = {
  'www.hello.com/12345': {value: 1, color: 'red'},
  'www.hello.com/0000': {value: 2, color: 'blue'}
}
function doFunc(s){
  for (const property in hrefMap ) {
    // console.log(property);
    if (property.indexOf(s) !== -1){
      console.log("that's it", property, ":", hrefMap[property]);
    }
  }
}

doFunc("12345");
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I tried this, but it's of type Map<string, any> and it's returning a blank array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hrefMap = {
'www.hello.com/12345': {value: 1, color: 'red'},
'www.hello.com/0000': {value: 2, color: 'blue'}
}

// Create an array of the keys, in this case the URL's
var strings = Object.keys(hrefMap);

// Function that accepts a string and gives back the possible urls
function returnUrl(search) {
  return strings.filter(s => s.indexOf(search) > -1);
}

// Example function
console.log(returnUrl('12345'))
console.log(returnUrl('0000'))
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I tried this, but it's of type Map<string, any> and it's returning a blank array.